# PHP If statement page split up

Tags: php, href

I'm currently using if statements to split up one document into multiple pages, this may be the wrong way to do it but it works.

For example each page is something like ?Page=PAGENAME

When i first load the page the href has to be stats.php?Page=Main

Is there a way to have the code default to page main? rather than it been hard coded into the  ?

Comment: Sure, just check & see if `_GET['Page']` is defined - if it's not, then display the main page.

Comment: sure, why not use a `case/switch` http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Answer (score 2):

This is really not the way to do it but in order to answer your question, you can put on top of your php the following:

```
$page = empty($_GET['Page']) ? 'Main' : $_GET['Page'];
```

This will result in $page having always a value, if the parameter is set then it will have this one, if not it will take the string 'Main'.

Comment: I don't think you can do it that way, as if the $_GET['Page'] isn't set, it would return an error since it would'nt be able to test $_GET['Page'], isset would be the way to go.

Comment: empty() method is also checking if the variable is set. This way it will also work if the user passes ?Page=